# How to intercept https request and serve content from local folder?

Tags: html, swift, https

I have an index.html page in assets folder (assets/webapp/index.html) and I want to load the content of that folder into web view but without using "loadFileURL" func (or fetching it over the internet). So the url would be something like this:

https://some.domain.net/webapp/index.html

and then I want for swift to intercept the request for "some.domain.net" and instead there go to my local assets folder where I have webapp folder. So protocol must be https but served locally.
I know that there is a way to do that in Android but I need the same in Swift. Is that possible? Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP stubs libraries [like this one](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs)

or

You can use a proxy [like this one](https://www.charlesproxy.com)

Or

You can use a dependency injection method to inject the webservice client and pass in the local client when you need to.